# VBA poke a default value in a cell when called from a cell formula

Tags: excel, vba

My objective seems simple enough, but it seems to get complicated with the object infrastructure.
I have one protected cell that gets a string value from another cell such as "Hello". After it does that and continuing in the same function, I want it to poke a default value of 2 into the adjacent cell to the right of it (which has no formula). The desired result is:

```
    Cell B3 = "Hello"
    Cell C3 = 2
```

Each row will get a similar value in column C. I've tried passing a range value of "C3" to the function, but it ends up passing a value of 1. I've also tried using the Application.caller function, to get the current cell address, but can't get it to convert to the adjacent cell. I'm losing something in the conversions.

```
=FormulaInCellB3(C3,"C3")
```

```
function FormulaInCellB3(int_C3 as integer, range_C3 as range)
' I've borrowed this code from others:
     With Application.Caller
          CallerRow = .Row
          CallerCol = .Column
          CallerAddr = .Address
     End With

     Dim Pos As Integer
     Dim Colx As String
     Dim Rowx As String
      
     Pos = InStr(2, CallerAddr, "$")
     Rowx = Mid(CallerAddr, Pos + 1)
     Colx = Mid(CallerAddr, 2, Pos - 2)

' From here, I have not been able to get a default value into cell C3
' I don't think the range value is passing correctly.

     FormulaInCellB3 = "Hello"

end function
```

Comment: a UDF called from the worksheet, by design, will not change the value of any cell other than the one in which the formula is placed.

Comment: You could maybe use an array formula and have your UDF return an array (see the second answer in the linked duplicate).